# Are there any modern history examples of large scale conflicts where warfare technology provides a great advantage to the defender, except WWI?

Tags: warfare, contemporary-history, modern, defense

One of the characteristics of World War I was the [Trench warfare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trench_warfare) which shows one of those cases when defender has a large advantage over the attacker:

> (..) a revolution in firepower was not matched by similar advances in
> mobility, resulting in a grueling form of warfare in which the
> defender held the advantage.

To me, the defender having such a great advantage over the attacker sounds more of an exception rather than something common. Some examples which emphasize attacker's advantage:

- cyberwarfare where it is [the attacker that has an advantage](https://www.cloudmask.com/blog/the-myth-of-staying-one-step-ahead-of-the-hackers)
- [rockets were developed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_rockets) way before the [anti-ballistic missiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-ballistic_missile#History) were developed

I am interested in examples of conflicts where warfare technology enabled the defender a significant advantage over the attacker.

Comment: I'd posture that city walls were a huge advantage for many centuries.

Comment: The US Civil War seems an obvious example.  The US lost more men in that war than in all its other military actions in its history *combined*.

Comment: @axsvl77 Yes, but I am wondering if this is still the case after the canons were invented.

Comment: [Your question does not have an authoritative answer](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4272/1401); can you revise the question to have an authoritative answer?

Comment: @MCW I have read your meta answer about "authoritative answer" which is incompatible with asking for lists. If my question can be interpreted as a list one and thus without an "authoritative answer", then any question about a situation repeating in the history is "bad" (no research and/or not useful and/or unclear). Indeed I see the problem of accepting an answer in this context. Is there any other reason why such a question is "bad'?

Comment: Precise artillery measurements and calculations benefited first fixed cannons (e.g., coastal artillery, which could hit warships with the first shot in the interwar period). Mobile army cannons or warships did not have the same precision fire capability, because their base was not fixed and calculations were more difficult, thus were at disavantage. It comes to a point when attacking coastal defences with ships become very difficult (see German attack on oslo)

Comment: @Alexei, H:SE is based on the assumption that every question has a single, authoritative answer that can be objectively identified.  That doesn't mean that questions without an authoritative answer are "bad", it just means they don't belong here.  The internet has plenty of places to discuss questions that don't fit here, and list questions belong in those places.  I clarified the meta-answer in response to your comment; thank you.

Comment: @T.E.D. - although having both sides count towards KIA kind of helps as well. And poor medical. But the first industrialized war by some measures.

Comment: I think Constantinople's city walls and use of greek fire are good examples of this.

Comment: Incidentally, there are StackExchange sites which allow "big-list" questions, where instead of a single authoritative answer, one gets a "big list" of answers. History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange (https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) is one of these. Make sure, you use the "big-list" as one of the tags.

Comment: Nuclear weapons seem like a perfect example. They have made successful offensive action of one great power against another impossible. The advantage is entirely to the  defense.

Comment: Vietnam, air war - the US managed to drop an obscene amount of bombs on north vietnam despite their best efforts at air defense. Was this because technology at this time favored attack or because of the material advantage the US had in terms of training, planes etc.?

Comment: The defender *always has been* at a stiff advantage. From Sun Tzu ("secure yourself against defeat first") to WWII and beyond ("it's over, Anakin, I have the high ground" -- sorry, could not resist), with virtually no exception in between. Any given military unit loses its ability at meaningful *offense* first, long before it loses the ability to *defend* itself -- because defending is much, much easier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Obvious example. Radar.

First radars during WWII were too heavy and had a short operational range. Hence, only the defender had the option of installing a radar to concentrate forces and defend certain places, the attacker didn't have the same alternative.

During the [Battle of Britain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Britain), the United Kingdom was capable of detecting German planes over the channel, giving UK pilots enough time to concentrate and reach altitude (that's an advantage in air battle).

Radar had the same effect in the [Battle of the Atlantic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Atlantic), once the radar was small enough, the UK put several of them in ships, so they were able to detect German submarines when they were on the surface (most submarine attacks were on the surface). The Germans lost several submarines without knowing that British had radars on their ships.

Comment: The US radar proximity fuze was developed between 1940 and 1942, with first shoot-down in the Solomons in January of 1943. To fit in a 5" shell takes a pretty small radar unit.

Comment: @JonCuster True, but the radar in an AA shell only needs to detect things within a few yards, not tens of miles.

Comment: @Ryan_L - getting fired from a gun adds some additional engineering issues as well...

Answer (score 2):

> the defender having such a great advantage over the attacker sounds more of an exception

This is a completely wrong concept. Every war expert will tell you that defending is always more cheaply done, in human lives and means used. This is no different today than it was in Antiquity or during the Middle Ages.

Since you ask for technology that gives the defender an advantage, I'll give a very plain example to reinforce the cheaply idea: **concrete cement**.

Comment: Even cheaper - a spade

Comment: yeah, a spade to move earth to protect yourself